Identify and call on excel sheets dynamically
I'm trying to build some code that will do some Vlookups between a variable number of sheets. I'd like to do this dynamically since the number of sheets in the workbook can and will be different.
Example:
I have a workbook that has 3 sheets named "FOB 1", "FOB 2", "FOB 3", "PPD 1" and "PPD 2"
I would then like to Vlookup column C from FOB 2 to FOB 1 and since it also exists I'd like to Vlookup FOB 3 to FOB 2 and FOB 1. And the same for the PPD sheets. (So PPD 2 vlookup into PPD 1).
Sheet names will always start with FOB or PPD. Each FOB or PPD could have any number of sheets but usually no more than 4 total sheets per type.
I am currently using a count that counts the number of sheets and I'm using a loop cycle through the sheets but I think what I need is a way to identify each sheet name for the vlookup? Is this possible, this isn't something I've done before. Any help or shove in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Current Code:
Sub TEST()
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim SheetCount As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim lrow As Long

SheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For I = 1 To SheetCount
With wb
.Worksheets(I).Activate
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If .Worksheets(I).Name Like "FOB *" And .Worksheets(I + 1).Name Like "FOB *" Then
       .Worksheets(I + 1).Range("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
       .Cells(2, 3).Resize(lrow - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'FOB 1'!C:C,1,0)"
    Else
    'do same thing for PPD sheets
    End If
 End With
Next I
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
END SUB


So for FOB 3 you'd insert two columns?  One each for FOB 1 and FOB 2?  Are there ever any "gaps"?  Eg. could you have FOB 1 and 3 but not 2 ?  Are the worksheets sorted by FOB/PPD number in the workbook ?

@TimWilliams No, each sheet after 1 will be compared to the previous sheets. So FOB 2 would vlookup into FOB 1, FOB 3 would be vlookup first into FOB 2 and then Vlookup into FOB 1. The idea is to remove all matchs between FOB 2 and FOB 3. Hopefully that makes sense. also yes they are sorted by FOB #, and then PPD # in sequential order.

"FOB 3 would be vlookup first into FOB 2 and then Vlookup into FOB 1."   It's unclear exactly how that would look though?

So my actual order of operation would be for FOB 3 to VLOOKUP into FOB 2 and then remove all rows that return a result. Then FOB 3 would VLOOKUP into FOB 1 and do the same. Then delete the added column.

And my other questions?

I think I answered them all? The sheets are always arranged as FOB # in sequential order, same with PPD #.

Sorry - my bad I did not see that...

No worries, appreciate any insight you might have. I am currently working on some idea's for this. My fall back is a loop check since, while the number of sheets is dynamic they never exceed 5 sheets for each type. So I could just write an IF/ELSIF for each scenario but was hoping to learn a better way to do this.

Here's a basic framework for how you might compare pairs of sheets in turn:
Sub Tester()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsPrev As Worksheet, col As Collection
    Dim itm, i As Long, p As Long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    For Each itm In Array("FOB", "PPD")
        Set col = MatchedSheets(wb, CStr(itm)) 'get matched worksheets from `wb`
        If col.Count > 1 Then            'any sheets to compare?
            For i = 2 To col.Count       'start with #2
                Set ws = col(i)          'the worksheet to operate on
                For p = 1 To i - 1       'loop all previous sheets
                    Set wsPrev = col(p)
                    Debug.Print "Comparing " & ws.Name & " with " & wsPrev.Name
                    'compare ws with wsPrev and delete matches from ws
                Next p
            Next i
        End If
    Next itm
End Sub

'Return a collection of all worksheets named like "txt*" from `wb`
Function MatchedSheets(wb As Workbook, txt As String) As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set MatchedSheets = New Collection
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, txt, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            MatchedSheets.Add ws
        End If
    Next ws
End Function


Thank you for this! Really appreciate your help and time.
